# Django unique, null and blank CharField giving 'already exists' error on Admin page

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-models

I've been getting the most weird error ever. I have a Person model

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    facebook_id = models.CharField(max_length=225, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    twitter_id = models.CharField(max_length=225, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    suggested_person = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I recently added the twitter_id field. When I access the Django admin page, and try to change the 'person' into a suggested_person, I get the following error:

```
 Person with this Twitter id already exists.
```

I find this error to be extremely strange because the Facebook_id field is designed the exact same way as the Twitter_id field.

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you have `null=True, blank=True` and  `unique=True`, django is considering `None` or blank as a unique entry. Remove the unique constraint and handle the uniqueness part in the code.

Comment: I deleted the Twitter_id field and then re-added it in using South. It's working fine now without giving me any issues

Comment: Django is treating a blank field as the empty string `''`, and the `unique=True` does not allow multiple entries with value `''`. It would however allow multiple entries with `twitter_id=None`.

Comment: See [Anentropic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29955359/10746224) for a detailed explanation about why this happens, and see [LondonAppDev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21934494/10746224) for a potential solution.

Answer (score 62):

None of the answers clearly describe the root of the problem.

Normally in the *db* you can make a field `null=True, unique=True` and it will work... because `NULL != NULL`. So each blank value is still considered unique.

But unfortunately for `CharField`s Django will save an empty string `""` (because when you submit a form everything comes into Django as strings, and you may have really wanted to save an empty string `""` - Django doesn't know if it should convert to `None`)

This basically means you shouldn't use `CharField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)` in Django. As others have noted you probably have to give up the db-level unique constraint and do your own unique checks in the model.

For further reference, see here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4136
(unfortunately no good solution decided at time of writing)

NOTE:
As pointed out by @alasdair in a comment, that bug has now been fixed - since Django 1.11 you can use `CharField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)` without having to manually convert blank values to `None`

Comment: Ticket 4136 has now been fixed. In Django 1.11+ you can use `CharField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)` without having to manually convert blank values to `None`.

Answer (score 24):

This is an old one but I had a similar issue just now and though I would provide an alternative solution.

I am in a situation where I need to be able to have a CharField with null=True, blank=True and unique=True. If I submit an empty string in the admin panel it will not submit because the blank string is not unique.

To fix this, I override the 'clean' function in the ModelForm, and in there I check if it's a blank string and return the result accordinly.

```
class MyModelChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel
        fields = ['email', 'name', 'something_unique_or_null',]

    def clean_something_unique_or_null(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['something_unique_or_null'] == "":
            return None
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data['something_unique_or_null']
```

This fixed the problem for me without having to sacrifice the unique attribute on the model field.

Hope this helps.

EDIT:
You need to change where I have put "something_unique_or_null" to the name of your field. For example "clean_twitter_id".

Comment: This is great but only for a particular form. The best solution is below from @shacker as it's applied to the model directly (will raise an exception for all forms, APIs, etc.).

Answer (score 14):

In Django 1.11, form `CharFields` will have an [`empty_value`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.CharField.empty_value) argument, which allows you to use `None` if the field is empty.

Model forms, including the Django admin, [will automatically set `empty_value=None`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types) if the model's `CharField` has `null=True`.

Therefore, you will be able to use `null=True`, `blank=True` and `unique=True` together in your model `CharField` without the unique constraint causing problems.

Comment: In my case (django `2.1.1`)  `a = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)` still saves empty strings instead of NULL :(

Comment: @chefarov if you're stuck please ask a new question. I can't help you in the comments.

Comment: He is right though. It seems that the second paragraph of your answer is wrong.

Comment: @DavidSchumann *form CharFields will have an empty_value* - but the second paragraph links to docs that say the same thing. I just tried `name = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, unique=True, max_length=20)` in Django 3.1, and it saves empty values as `None`, as expected.

Answer (score 12):

It's important to solve this at the model level, not at the form level, since data can enter through APIs, through import scripts, from the shell, etc. The downside of setting `null=True` on a CharField is that the column could end up with both empty strings and NULLs, which is slightly ambiguous but not generally a problem in my experience. If you're willing to live with that ambiguity, here's how to do it in a few steps:

1) Set `null=True, blank=True` on the field and migrate in the change.

2) Massage your data so that all existing empty strings are changed to NULLs:

```
items = Foo.objects.all()
for item in items:
  if not item.somefield:
    item.somefield = None
    item.save()
```

3) Add a custom `save()` method to your model:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Empty strings are not unique, but we can save multiple NULLs
    if not self.somefield:
        self.somefield = None

    super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Python3-style super()
```

4) Set `unique=True` on the field and migrate that in as well.

Now you'll be able to store `somefield` as empty or as a unique value whether you're using the admin or any other data entry method.

If you prefer not to have several migrations, here's an example of how to do it in a single migration:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import migrations, models

def set_nulls(apps, schema_editor):
    Event = apps.get_model("events", "Event")
    events = Event.objects.all()
    for e in events:
        if not e.wdid:
            e.wdid = None
            e.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('events', '0008_something'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='event',
            name='wdid',
            field=models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=32, null=True),
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(set_nulls),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='event',
            name='wdid',
            field=models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=32, null=True, unique=True),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: I would change it to : `if self.somefield is not None and self.somefield.strip() == ''` to avoid useless override when nothing changed.

Comment: I've tried this, but I find that my custom "save" method isn't called when I press save on the Admin page. (And I'm still getting a fail because my empty text box is non-unique.) I wonder if there's some sort of pre-filtering going on at the form level that's preventing the model save?

Answer (score 8):

The root of the problem is that Django persist the empty value as empty-string, and not as null. To fix this, you can subclass `CharField` as follows:

```
class CharNullField(models.CharField):
    description = "CharField that stores NULL"
    
    def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection=None, prepared=False):
        value = super(CharNullField, self).get_db_prep_value(value, connection, prepared)
        if value=="":
            return None
        else:
            return value
```

So `get_db_prep_value` will make it sure that null gets persisted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide `default=None` in the field

```
facebook_id = models.CharField(max_length=225,unique=True, null=True,blank=True,default=None)
```

This worked for me . I used it in phone number. So it can be unique if entered and not mandatory.

Answer (score -1):

you are accepting blank values and expect them to be unique. this means there can only be ONE entry with a blank twitter_id

you can

- either remove the unique contraint
- remove the blank =True
- give a default value for the field ( but default needs to be unique)

Comment: Default value wont work. Again same issue. Also removing blank would cause more issues

Comment: oh yes, the unique constraint. but the default value can come from a function or something.